# How to share global memory within multiple kernels and multiple GPUs?

Tags: cuda, qualifiers

```
----------------a.c---------------------
variable *XX;
func1(){
  for(...){
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       cutStartThread(func2,args)
  } 
}
---------------b.cu-------------------
func2(args){
  cudaSetDevice(i);
  xx = cudaMalloc();
  mykernel<<<...>>>(xx);
}
--------------------------------------
```

Recently, I want to use multiple GPU device for my program. There are four Tesla C2075 cards on my node. I use four threads to manage the four GPUs. What's more, the kernel in each thread is launched several times. A simple pseudo code as above. I have two questions:

1. Variable `XX` is a very long string, and is read only in the kernel. I want to preserve it during the multiple launches of `mykernel`. Is it ok to call `cudaMalloc` and pass the pointer to `mykernel` only when  `mykernel` is first launched? Or should I use `__device__` qualifier?
2. `XX` is used in four threads, so I declare it as a global variable in file `a.c`. Are multiple `cudaMalloc` of `XX` correct or should I use an array such as `variable *xx[4]`?

Comment: Don't use `cuStartThread()` in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

1. For usage by kernels running on a single device, you can call `cudaMalloc` once to create your variable `XX` holding the string, then pass the pointer created by cudaMalloc (i.e. `XX`) to whichever kernels need it.

   ```
   #define xx_length 20
   char *XX;
   cudaMalloc((void **)&XX, xx_length * sizeof(char));
   ...
   kernel1<<<...>>>(XX, ...);
   ...
   kernel2<<<...>>>(XX, ...);
   etc.
   ```
2. Create a separate XX variable for each thread, assuming that each thread is being used to access a different device. How exactly you do this will depend on the scope of XX.   But an array of:

   ```
   char *XX[num_devices];
   ```

at global scope, should be OK.

The CUDA [OpenMP sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cudaopenmp) may be of interest as an example of how to use multiple threads to manage multiple GPUs.